# (Unofficial) Stack Overflow, Windows Phone app forgets its place when sleeping

Tags: support, windows-phone

Sometimes, when I'm reading a question on [this (unofficial) Stack Overflow, Windows Phone app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/overflow/1ac365bc-2c53-4902-b0e6-440bfb01a45f), the phone goes to sleep.
When I wake it up, it's forgotten I was reading a question, and has gone back to the main screen. This is really annoying.

Comment: Which app are you using?

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/stackoverflow/1ac365bc-2c53-4902-b0e6-440bfb01a45f - This is the app am using.

Comment: Looking through our Windows Phone apps, the one you're using doesn't seem to be listed here. You may be out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: What's the purpose of that comma, @BrockAdams?

Comment: @TRiG, Which comma?  http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives ? ... PS: do you really want to spend much effort debating a comma here?  This isn't tax law or the Second Amendment or anything.